# Why is MYSQL insert slow on difference virtual machine same ram and cpu

Tags: mysql, performance, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a problem which MYSQL performance insert on difference machine same ram and cpu.

I'm run MYSQL on VM Window 2k3 4GB of Ram, 4 CPUs build on VMWare Workstaion 12 run on my PC vs VM Window 2k3 4GB of Ram, 4 CPUs build on ESXi 6.5 on Server. Of course all hardware of Server is better than my PC.

MYSQL on my PC executes 3000 queries insert in 1.5s but on Server executes 3000 queries insert in 48s. what is the problem?

2 VM have same my.ini config:

```
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1


[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"

datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"
character-set-server=latin1

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_connections=500

query_cache_size=0

table_cache=256

tmp_table_size=18M

thread_cache_size=8

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=35M

key_buffer_size=25M

read_buffer_size=64K

read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

sort_buffer_size=256K

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=47M

innodb_log_file_size=24M

innodb_thread_concurrency=18
```

When i config `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 0 or 2 Server run very fast in 0.5s but i want to know what is the difference when `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` is 1 on my PC executes in 1.5s but Server executs in 48s?

Comment: If you want to know why, from your two MySQL hosts for comparison/analysis, please post SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS: this would be an interesting evaluation. 09/03/2017

Comment: Vuong Minh, except that this system will not support the VOLUME of data from these three requests. An alternative is to post TEXT output to pastebin.com and share the links with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3000/48 is about a spinning drive's speed (Rule of Thumb: 10ms per I/O).  So that sounds like `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`.

3000/1.5 sounds better than even SSD, so I am guessing there is a RAID controller with Battery Backed Write cache, which would make most writes almost instantaneous.  And having the set of `1` would be no problem.  Or perhaps the drive has a write cache that is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are right my PC use SSD drive and my Server use SAS VelociRaptor 600GB 10K but why speed is so different 1.5s vs 48s?

Comment: 30x faster is more than I would expect, so I am guessing there is a "write cache".  You may notice that spinning drives are vanishing; SSDs are taking over.  This is one reason.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it as 1 will help innodb to be ACID COMPLIANT. If you set it to 1, log buffer will be written to log file soon after each transaction commits. But if you set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0, the same will be done once per second. Actually this might be the cause why the insertion time differs.  By default, it is set to 1. When it is set to 2, logs will be written to the file when a transaction gets committed but the flush to disk operation will not be done each time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my problem is both virtual machine set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 1, on my pc run 3000 queries insert on 1.5s and server run 3000 queries insert on 48s and i want to know why :(

Answer (score 0):

WHY could be determined by providing
VM number of similar accounts sharing the VM host  TOTAL RAM of VM host.  And from your two MySQL hosts for comparison/analysis,
RAM in GB and

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:
```

this would be an interesting evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both my PC and Server have 1 VM. My PC 16GB Ram with SSD 256G, Server 128GB ram with 2xSAS VelociRaptor 10k RAID 1 600GB

Comment: And from your two MySQL hosts for comparison/analysis, please post  
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:
this would be an interesting evaluation.

Comment: Vuong Minh, except that this system will not support the VOLUME of data from these three requests. An alternative is to post TEXT output to pastebin.com and share the links with us.

Answer (score 0):

@Vuong Minh  We could determine WHY only with

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

for each of your HOSTS.  Hoping you can add this information to your Question.

Comment: Vuong Minh, except that this system will not support the VOLUME of data from these three requests.  An alternative is to post TEXT output to pastebin.com and share the links with us.